# Javascript onClick won't fire getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to ask why won't my Javascript function do the enclosed jQuery function $.getJSON()?

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input id="search" name="search" type="text" class="map-search form-control input-sm"/>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
         <input class="map-search btn btn-default btn-sm" type="submit" onclick="nominatim_search()" />
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </span>
</form>
```

**Javacript**

```
function nominatim_search() {
    var query = document.getElementById("search").value;
    $.getJSON('http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/ph/'+query+'?format=json&limit=1&polygon_geojson=1&bounded=1&addressdetails=1', function (boundary) {
        var json = boundary[0].geojson;
        L.geoJSON(json).addTo(map);
  });
}
```

It would enter the function however and alert the query, however the JSON won't load. I would outside of the function.

Comment: We need a little more information, are you sure jQuery is available at the time of executing the function? Are you sure the function is even being called. Maybe put a `console.log()` at the first line of the function and checking the developer tools `console` tab would help :)

Comment: @Abdel thanks for your time. I actually put an alert box inside the function and it gets executed. I still did what you suggested and made console.log() after submit nothing appears in the console tab. But someone already suggested a solution. Though I would want to understand why submit won't work for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input isn't a templated tag, so you must close it without put other tag inside:

```
<input class="map-search btn btn-default btn-sm" type="submit" onclick="nominatim_search()" />
```

The form `<input> ..... </input>` isn't valid for html

**UPDATE**

To solve the issue, it's mandatory to change the input type="submit", because the submit causes the reload of the page before the end of the function in the script. In the comment section of this answer, I suggest to use input type="button" and that did the trick. Other solutions like replace the input with a `<button type="button">` tag are good enough to be considered as valid for this question, maybe a `<button type="button">` tag is more compliant to the question needs because it's a templated tag, so it can be written with other tag inside.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. however the jquery still doesn't execute.

Comment: @Reiion I think that's because it's a submit, the page reload itself before the function is ended, try to change type="submit" with type="button"

Answer (score 0):

You didnt close input tag, just add `>`:

```
<input class="map-search btn btn-default btn-sm" type="submit" onclick="nominatim_search()">
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. however the jquery still doesn't execute.

Answer (score 0):

Here Just try Replacing your markups with these. Since your using Span for modifying the text of the button, use `<button>` instead of `<input>`.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input id="search" name="search" type="text" class="map-search form-control input-sm">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="map-search btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button" onclick="nominatim_search()" />
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </button>
    </span>
</form>
```

Let me know if it helped with your problem.

Comment: thank you for your help, this didn't resolve the problem but it made my html page look better haha thanks for your time